# My Django/MySQL Login project don’t work, how can i fix it?

Tags: python, mysql, django, authentication, modulenotfounderror

I created a login page, but I'm having trouble with an error message that says 'ModuleNotFoundError: no module named "login.settings".' I've checked my code and everything looks fine, but when I try to start the server, this error message appears. I've tried various solutions but I'm still not sure what's causing the issue. If you need more information or pictures, please let me know. I'm hoping to resolve this soon so I can get some rest. Thanks for your help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9fac.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your folder structure is not correct if I understand your IDE correctly.

It should be set up like this:

```
your_project/
  - your_project/
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
    - ...
 
  - your_app/
    - __init__.py
    - admin.py
    - ...

  - manage.py
```

You probably have renamed some folders along the way. Why has the folder that contains your settings.py not the same name as your project?

I don't know if simple renaming does the trick for you now. If you just started the project, I would start a new project (this time without a hyphen inside the folder name, use underscore).

Setup the folderstructure with `django-admin startproject djangotest` ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#startproject)). Then, inside of that folder you want to do `django-admin startapp login` ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#startapp)). This makes sure that you have all name and structure related things set up correctly.

Now **be careful** when copying over the files from your old project. Do it one by one and not as an entire folder since this might mess it up again.